# Deploying a Laravel app on CPanel from Github - the right way

Tags: laravel, npm, deployment, cpanel

I'm new to shared hosting deployment and I need help to deploy an app on a shared hosting server that uses CPanel.

I have deployed thee same app before on a CPanel shared hosting, by zipping my files and uploading them to the subdomain. But as far as I am concerned, that is very wrong since all my development files are exposed to anybody

Second time I tried, I copied the files from the git repo via SSH, and the installing composer, but when I try to install node to use npm and run the command `npm install` and `npm run dev`. Surprise! I had errors such as `Javascript heap out of memory` Zone allocation failed and Aborted.

So I would like to know:

> How to install properly node dependencies from a laravel package.json file on CPanel, without breaking down the server or misconfiguring something

Any help would be very appreciated. I there's a way to granmt or reward anyone here, I would like you to show me how.

I have to get this working before next saturday, therefore any help would be very nice.

This is my package.json, just in case you need it:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "^0.2.1",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
        "alpinejs": "^2.7.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "laravel-mix-merge-manifest": "^2.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "sweetalert2": "^10.16.0"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest if you're getting memory errors that you add more memory to the machine. This has nothing to do with how you copy files to and from the machine.

Comment: Since it's a shared hosting service, I've tried but still getting same errors. Mostrly the one that says that javascript heaps out of memory...

Comment: Then I would suggest focusing your search on that error message, instead of asking about file transfer methods!

Answer (score 1):

So what happened here, is that I had to delete all `node_modules` folder. Then, I ran `npm update --legacy-peer-deps` command in order to have all packages according to the package.json file. After that, I could run

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

without further complications.